# White letters in header

Tags: customization

Hello i have some strange issue with the header it was normal in black and know is white and i dont know how is happen. i cant change because not recognized the block

i was searching the solution but is about different issues than me i think that is simple platform issue.

[image: white letters]

````
BLOGGING
BOOKKEEPER

<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>-nnnnnnnnnnnnnnn </p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->```
````

Answer (score 1):

since you are using a block editor, you should be able to select the text, and then set the color.

[image: Select the text and click dropdown icon to select text color.]

[image: NOw , select the color you want.]